# what software should i use when i want to study c 

Tags: c, compiler-construction

i want to write code use notepad and compile the c code use `cmd` on windows (like java),

what software should i use ,

1. gcc for windows
2. cygwin
3. Turbo C
4. gvim

thanks

Comment: No, you don't want to write code using Notepad.   That's just wrong.  Whether you go into Visual Studio IDE land, or stick with text editors like gvim, Notepad++, or Programmer's Notepad, **DON'T USE NOTEPAD** unless you have no other option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An excellent option for Windows is the [Visual C++ Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/) (which is free). This is a full IDE, compiler, and debugger and is a great way to get started.

GCC is also a good option if for some reason you wish to avoid an IDE. I wouldn't recommend this for a beginner, though.

Please *don't* use Turbo C, it's very old and you will have problems with it.

Comment: If you really, really want to go with Borland then at least use Borland C++ 5.5 available for free from http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20633.

Comment: Visual C++ (of any variety) is not a good choice if you want to learn C, since it does not support C. Its C standard library functions do not conform to any version of the C standard, and they're basically unmaintained.

Comment: Turbo C could actually refer to a free version of the RAD tool released in 2006, named after the DOS-based dinosaur from 1991. Anyway, neither are suitable for a beginner.

Answer (score 5):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a popular linux environment for Windows.

Gvim is an editor and (in my opinion) has a *very high* learning curve.  You could use Notepad++ or Code::Blocks to develop your code in.

Answer (score 3):

mingw is also a good option to start with.

Comment: Without offering a link as well, this answer may not be understandable to newbe's like the OP.

Answer (score 2):

IMO you should avoid IDEs: a beginner needs to actually see and feel the whole process of compiling by invoking the compiler from a terminal, not by simply pressing some keys and bang! Also most of the IDEs have code completion facilities which is not good for beginners (especially for C).  So I would go with vim (or gvim) and cygwin.

PS: Give Linux a try, you might actually like it; then vim and gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Use cygwin. It's just about the only way to get a C environment on Windows that's both modern (i.e. not 16-bit, DOS-based) and conformant to the standards, and with it you get a fairly-complete POSIX environment, which allows you to actually *do interesting things* with C.

Answer (score 1):

The classics would be Cygwin and MSYS/MinGW.

Cygwin provides a Linux API compatibility layer and includes a package manager which provides access to many well-known Linux applications (ie batteries included).

MSYS/MinGW only provides a minimal userland to get the GNU build system working.

Both come with their own shell environment, but can be used from Windows' command line as well.

Binaries created with Cygwin-gcc won't work without `cygwin1.dll`, but you get all the benefits of a mostly-POSIX environment. You can also use Cygwin's MinGW package for cross-compilation and thus create stand-alone binaries.

Other solutions are possible: Currently, I'm using the MinGW compiler together with the Cygwin userland from the Windows command line...

Answer (score 0):

I think cygwin itself named as gcc for windows.
also gvim is not a compiler , It is a very nice and powerful tool for code editing.Also you can try emacs and kwrite

Some suggestions from my side:

In windows, you need to install a third party software to try all programming stuffs(c,c++ etc) ,Most of the times it is having GUI implementations and you didn't get any exact idea behind the code execution flow.also the command prompt of windows not at all efficient as linux shell.

But if you install a good linux distro (ubuntu/fedora/cent os/debian/pardus/suse/arch linux),all default compilers,debuggers and editors are installed within the OS and you can try the basic and all advanced programs by just opening the terminal(shell).Also the shell is a more powerful tool and you can enjoy all kind of automation comamnds(I mean scripting).

Also: for your added information, most of the embedded programmers in the industry prefer command line execution unlike GUI implementation because it is too fast than GUI.